# How to show an image from ListView in DialogFragment

Tags: listview, dialogfragment

I`m new to Android and I need to show a DialogFragment over ListView Activity. ListView has an image and the text. When OnItemClick is pressed I need to show only the image in custom DialogFragment, but I have no idea how to pass image to the DialogFragment class.

Comment: the question's title is misleading, you don't need to show a ListView into the DialogFragment but an image taken from it.

Comment: I`ve changed the title.  Hope this one is more comprehensive

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use the code in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#BasicDialog) modifing the `newInstance()` method to accept a `Drawable`.

To pass the `Drawable` from the `ListView` to the dialog when clicked you have to use the `setOnListItemClickListener()` as the following (**untested**) code:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            Drawable d = iv.getDrawable();

            MyFragmentDialog df = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(d);
            df.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Looks simple, I`ll try this. Thank you